# Value to configure without having to submit a form with change function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a checkout page that I am trying to configure tax with. It is a simple tax amount. It is if someone lives in Ohio the value is 1.065 and if they are in any other state in the US it is nothing.

I'm not the best at using JavaScript with PHP, so this may be why I am having difficulties. I am trying to configure this without submitting a form. When the customer has to click the drop down box to select a state, I want this to configure then. I am not submitting a form until much later in this page and I want them to see the value right away.

I start by having a list of arrays with all of the states like this..

```
$taxvalue['Ohio'] = 1.065;
$taxvalue['Wyoming'] = 1;
```

Then I am making a variable for the tax amounts:

```
$taxed_state = 1.065;
$untaxed_state = 1;
```

Then I'm checking if the state is set and adding the taxed variable to it.

```
if(isset($taxvalue['Ohio'])){
            $taxed_state;
       } else {
         $untaxed_state;
    }
```

This is how I'm going to configure the total with the tax.

```
   $base_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];


            }
            $tax_price += $base_price * $taxed_state;
            $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;
```

The tax rate is then displayed here, but I'm having issues with the tax rate not showing up here. I'm also not sure if I am coding it right so the tax and total will always be correct.

```
<p>Tax: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $tax_price //- $base_price;
```

The form when entering the state:

```
<label for="state">State</label>
        <select type="text" class="mediuminputbar preview" id="ShipTostate" data-copy="#confirmstate" name="ShipTostate" required>
            <option value=''>Select a State</option>
                <?php
                foreach($taxvalue as $key => $val) {
                    echo "<option value='$val'>$key</option>/n";
                }   
                ?>
        </select>
```

The Javascript I am trying to use with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    var taxed_state = 0;
    var base_total = 0;

    $( "#taxvalue" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Ohio') {
            taxed_state = 1.065;
        }
        else {
            taxed_state = 1;
        }
        $('#taxed_price').val(base_total * taxed_state);
    });
});
});
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working or what it is that I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the `#taxvalue` element? Your state select element is `id="ShipTostate"`. (Also, `$(function() { ...})` creates a document ready handler - you don't need to wrap that in `$(document).ready(function() {...})`, though that wouldn't stop it working.)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` does the exact same thing as `$(function() {` . Don't use both at same time

Comment: Am I able to have two elements? I use id="ShipTostate" for something else. I thought I had to have #taxvalue to get the php variable.

Comment: I need the tax value to show up here and if it is not set to be at $0 as a default.. <p>Tax: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $tax_price //- $base_price;